# JS/ Regex A better way to get RGBa values from a string

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm using this code to convert a string like `"rgb(200, 12, 53, 0.96)"`to an array of numbers

this is my code

```
var rgb = 'rgb(200, 12, 53, 0.96)'.match(/\d+/g);
console.log(rgb);
```

but the output wrongly push 0 and 96 as separate values

how can I keep floating numbers together? i have no idea how regex works sorry

Comment: maybe with simple `var rgb = 'rgb(200, 12, 53, 0.96)'.match(/[\d\.]+/g);`

Answer (score 4):

`0.96` contains a decimal that doesn't match `\d`, you can add `.` with `\d` in a character class wrapped in `[]` to match float numbers:

```js
var rgb = 'rgb(200, 12, 53, 0.96)'.match(/[.\d]+/g);
console.log(rgb);
```